# GridView simulate onClick Agenda

Tags: android, gridview, calendar, onclick

In my Application I have an Agenda build from a GridView.
I want to perform an simulated onClick on a specific position on the GridView(the current day ofcourse), I couldnt find a solution to my problem.

Target build is 2.2
Any Sugestions to handle my problem would be great.

edit: I mean onItemClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can`t be done, cause of Google`s Android Design.